# JSON encode in as3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, json

Can any one provide me with an example of how to encode data and pass it to a php file using JSON and flash?

Answer (score 4):

You can use fast [actionjson](http://blog.brokenfunction.com/2010/10/30/actionjson-the-fastest-actionscript-3-0-json-parser/) library for it. And vote for native encoder/decoder in ActionScript ([FP-1631](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1631))

Now you can use native JSON with Flash Player 11